# How to pass variables from one file to another?

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I have managed to get the total cost and called the variable "Cost". Now as i need this to be displayed on another page called confirmation page, i have to use cookies which will get the variable "Cost" , which will have the total price and insert into the new file, the confirmation page.

So the user clicks on the number of adults the want and clicking checkout, the total price is already displayed but as the checkout button directs the user to the confirmation page, the Total cost variable "Cost" is displayed. 
I was told that cookies is best to do this but cant manage to insert it to my website.

Comment: Can you post the code you have so far?

Comment: How are you navigating to the confirmation page? href? you can pass url parameters

Comment: On an e-commerce site this behaviour would normally be handled by a session on the server.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask

Comment: to navigate through the pages i used : setTimeout(function() {window.location ="confirmation.html"});